# Bash Scripting ^-...------ | wc …

Tags: bash, shell, word-count

What does that line mean?

`^-...------ | wc ...`

It is a part of a Bash script.

Comment: it looks a [pipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) but the first command name is weird.

Comment: It doesn't look meaningful to me. The part before `|` should be a command whose output will be piped to `wc`, but that doesn't look like a real command.

Comment: Could you show more of the script?

Comment: I cannot, I am sorry. This is all I have got. I guess, that the three dots once were rwx.

Comment: That first part looks like a regular expression to me. Is it possible this was part of something like `ls -l | grep ^-...------ | wc -l` ?

Comment: That is possible, yes. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to write:

```
ls -l | grep ^.......... | wc -l
```

the output of `ls -l` will be piped, and this will return the number of *all* files, because `.` matches any character.

In your case, someone wanted to count number of files that only (might) have *owner permission*, that's why the pattern doesn't care about first three flags.

Look for example at this line:

```
-rw-------  1 root   root    35 Jun 15 15:32 .smbpasswd
↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Not that the line `^-...------ | wc ...` by itself is invalid.

(Thought about that after I read @GordonDavisson comment, thanks)

Comment: I guess the original first command name might be `grep ^-...------`, because the `^` is an anchor used in regular expressions and the ouptut of `ls -l` command shows the file type at the first column.

Comment: I guess, that there is a grep command. What is counted with the wc command?

Comment: @Exception, I guess the purpose might be to count the number of entries in a directory which have no permission for group users and others.

Comment: That is something I understand. ;-) Thanks, Jdamian!